# How to Reject rows while loading files with extra comma's in SSIS Packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I want to reject rows while loading data from flat file to Sql server and handle the rows with extra comma's and redirect them to flat file

Example

```
ID,FirstName,LastName,City
1,Robert,Gurera,Phoenix
2,Tom,Bradley,Cleveland,5
3,Jack,Williams,Dallas
4,Tim,Doherthy,San franscisco,6,7
```

I want to reject row 2 and 4 and load them to a flat file

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple:

1. Create a Flat file source. Go to Advanced, and add a new column `column 5` as shown below

[image: img]

2. Next, check in the columns. What you need to do is, use `conditional split transformation` to redirect rows having data in column 5 to another destination.

[image: img2]

Make sure to add few more columns if you're sure about length coming from flat file.

Comment: Hi Prabhat,
Thanks for response.Can you explain the scenario in case if we are not sure about the number of extra columns?

Comment: @JoeRoot At that time, then you'll have to import it in database table, under 1 column. Then use sql string functions to bifurcate.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to check I would check using a script component source:

Load into one column and split.

If length is correct then send the row to the data flow otherwise send it out a failure path (most likely to a flat file or something.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

I just looked at your data and you would be OK using split and just processing the left 4 columns (0-3).

Here's the code:

```
using System.IO;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using(var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\test.csv"))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(','); //Make sure single quote to represent char

            if(values.length == 4)
            {
                 Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                 Output0Buffer.Id=int.Parse(values[0]);
                 Output0Buffer.Fname = values[1];
                 Output0Buffer.LastName = values[2];
                 Output0Buffer.City = values[3];
            }
            else
            {
                  BadRowBuffer.AddRow();
                  BadRowBuffer.BadRow = line.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to set up the outputs.

Comment: Keep in mind I typed this into the answer so there may be Capital issues.